# I2C communication Raspberry Pi 3 and Arduino

Tags: c++, arduino, i2c, raspberry-pi3

(sorry for bad English, I'm German)

Hello programmers,

I'm trying (without success) to send data from an Raspberry Pi 3(master) to an Arduino(slave):

Here's my **updated** Arduino Code:

```
#include <Wire.h>
volatile bool flag = false;
void wireHandler(int numBytes)
{
  flag = true;
}
void setup()
{
  pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
  Wire.begin(0x23);
  Wire.onReceive(wireHandler);
}
void loop()
{
  delay(100);
  digitalWrite(13, flag);
}
```

My Raspy code (C++, g++ main.cpp -lwiringPi):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <wiringPiI2C.h>
int main(void)
{
    if(wiringPiSetup() == -1)
    {
        std::cerr << "wiringPiSetup() == -1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if(wiringPiI2CSetup(0x39) == -1) //is 0x39 correct?
    {
        std::cerr << "wiringPiI2CSetup(int) == -1\n";
        return 1;
    }
    while(true)
    {
        wiringPiI2CWrite(0x23, 0x23);
        delay(100);
    }
}
```

In theory this should make the Arduino Led (pin 13) blink.
However the led stays dark.

I would be thankful if anyone could explain me why this program does not work and how to fix it.

And yes I2C is activated in Raspi-Config.

Answer (score 0):

The `Wire.onReceive()` handler is called from `ISR` handler and therefore all other ISRs are blocked. Including the one counting `millis` and without it, `delay()` can't work as it's relying on `millis`.

For example some `volatile` variable should be updated by this event and handled in `loop()`, as `ISR` handlers must be as short as possible.

For example this one will light if received byte LSB is 1.

```
#include <Wire.h>

volatile byte recv = 0;

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(0x23);               // join i2c bus with address #8
  Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent); // register event
  //Serial.begin(57600);          // start serial for output
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  delay(10);
  digitalWrite(13, recv);
}

void receiveEvent(int howMany) {
  while (Wire.available()) { 
    byte c = Wire.read();
    recv = c & 1; // just last character and its LSB will be used
  }
}
```

On the other side is another arduino (as I just don't have RPi) sending incrementing byte sequence. One value every 500ms. This makes the first arduino blink:

```
#include <Wire.h>

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
}

byte x = 0;

void loop() {
  Wire.beginTransmission(0x23); // transmit to device #8
  Wire.write(x);              // sends one byte
  byte error = Wire.endTransmission();     // stop transmitting

  Serial.print("Sent: ");
  Serial.print(x,DEC);
  Serial.print(" ");
  Serial.println(error, DEC);

  x++;
  delay(500);
}
```

But basically only 0 or 1 value can be sent to turn off or turn on the led.

Comment: Thank you, now that you say this it makes sense. However it still does not work. Any Input?

Comment: Thank you for your help, but this isn't really solving my problem: If the slave is an arduino with my code and the master is another arduino everything works fine. But if the master is a raspberry it doesn't work anymore. Is it possible, that the problem is that the raspberry has a 3,3V logic?

Comment: At least you know it's not on the arduino side. Start with commands like `i2cdetect` and `i2cset`. Or use whole [tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-spi-and-i2c-tutorial) as you have to make sure, it is working. Even with some I2C eeprom or so. And get some level shifter to be sure.

Comment: What are your hardware connections? I just resolved my I2C issues between raspi master and arduino slave by connecting their grounds together.

Comment: @velotron It's called two wire communication, but common ground is essential (it's just not counted as communication line).